# Laravel 10 Passport - Client authentication failed - OAuthServerException

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, laravel-10

I have started a fresh Laravel 10 REST API project and have set up everything as stated in the Laravel Passport documentation, but I am encountering the following error.

```
"message": "There was some internal error",
    "result": null,
    "exception": {
        "message": "Client authentication failed",
        "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/league\/oauth2-server\/src\/Exception\/OAuthServerException.php",
        "line": 154,
        "code": 4,
        "trace": [
            {
                "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/league\/oauth2-server\/src\/Grant\/AbstractGrant.php",
                "line": 199,
                "function": "invalidClient",
                "class": "League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException",
                "type": "::"
            },
            {
                "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/passport\/src\/Bridge\/PersonalAccessGrant.php",
                "line": 21,
                "function": "validateClient",
                "class": "League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Grant\\AbstractGrant",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/league\/oauth2-server\/src\/AuthorizationServer.php",
                "line": 201,
                "function": "respondToAccessTokenRequest",
                "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\Bridge\\PersonalAccessGrant",
                "type": "->"
            },
```

My login function :

```
 $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (!auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->apiResponse(
                [
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Unauthorized',
                    'alerts'=> ["type"=>"error","message"=>"Your Email address or Password is wrong"]
                ],
                401
            );
        }

        /* ------------ Create a new personal access token for the user. ------------ */
        $tokenData = auth()->user()->createToken('Personal Access Client');
        $token = $tokenData->accessToken;
        $expiration = $tokenData->token->expires_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());
```

I have reset the database and re-installed Passport. I am working with port 8001, and I have also set it to 8000 because I read somewhere that it might play a role.

Comment: Have you followed the [installation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#installation) correcly?
1)changes on `config/auth.php` to the `'driver' => 'passport'`
2)create a row on DB `php artisan passport:client --personal` for the token.
3)check if your keys are ok with `php artisan passport:keys`

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error what i did was to remove
Passport::hashClientSecrets(); in the boot method of the AuthServiceProvider